# Incorrect POST using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Following these instructions
http://robertogds.com/post/3324511589/howto-backbone-js-using-rails-3

The issue/error is that the content is never saved to the db.  Using Firebug it appears that the POST json request is incorrect:
content
    "empty todo..." 
done
    false
text
    "test"

Basically, the backbone.js event fires a json update that takes the input data ("test") and creates a new model attribute "text" instead of updating the "content" data attribute...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the author of that post forgot a few steps.  The todos.js file needed to include some changes to make sure the :text variable (in the backbone.js todo example) was changed to :content

for example the setText function

```
var text = this.model.get('content');
```

the close function

```
// Close the `"editing"` mode, saving changes to the todo.
    close: function() {
      this.model.save({content: this.input.val()});
      $(this.el).removeClass("editing");
    },
```

and the createOnEnter function

```
// create new **Todo** model persisting it to *localStorage*.
    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      var text = this.input.val();
      if (!text || e.keyCode != 13) return;
      Todos.create({content: text});
      this.input.val('');
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling save on the Backbone.js model like this:

```
t = new Todo;

t.set({ 'content' : 'test' });

t.save();
```

Or are you doing this:

```
t = new Todo;

t.save({ 'content' : 'test' });
```

Also is there any output from the web server into console when you try and save the model? That may help narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: i figured it out...  the instructions forgot to include the need to update Todo.js to make sure the :text variable in the example Todo app was updated to :content.  So, without setting the value it was sending the default value to the server (which i knew from the json post)